# How can I restore leather color?

Tags: cleaning, interior, leather

My wife has an '01 Accord, light grey interior.  Her leather wrapped steering wheel was gunky and sticky and probably has never been cleaned, so I bought some leather cleaner, conditioner (both chemical guys), and some microfiber cloths and went to work.

The wheel was light grey to match the interior, but now its mostly black.  My research leads me to believe the UV light, sweat, body oil, and time eroded the color/coating on the leather and now we're left with just "leather".

Is there some way to dye, or refinish, the wheel leather?

I was thinking something along these lines: http://www.leatherworldtech.com/Acura-Honda-Leather-Dye-Colors-s/1844.htm

Comment: My personal experience with leather dyes and refinishing products is they rub off pretty quickly.  I would recommend just [buying a new one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/272158078398). Not my sale - just one I found for you.

Comment: Yes, the color rubs off on your clothes.

Comment: Leather has layers, naturally, they can peel and you see the difference in color, it happens on jackets too. There are products on the market that try to repair the damage adding the missing layer, you buy the color that match, its not dye, think colored glue if you want an idea. I never used them so cant say how good they are. Heard of people using Plastidip, it peels off so you might want more than one coat all around to obtain a sort of steering wheel cover... that it peels off is an advantage if you want to get rid of it at least.